# Attaching workflow to a custom form web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, web-part, workflow, infopath

I don't have access to InfoPath.

I am making a custom web part with a basic form having 4 fields and a submit button. I want to start a workflow when user presses submit button? Can I do this in my custom form? I mean running some workflow on button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a workflow programmatically with the code from [here](http://blog.mmasood.com/2012/06/programatically-start-workflow.html)

```
private SPWorkflowAssociation GetWorkflowAssociationByName(SPListItem item, string workflowAssociationName) 
{ 
    return item.ContentType.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName(workflowAssociationName, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")); 

} 

public void StartWorkflow(SPListItem item, string associationName) 
{ 
  try
   {                 
//get workflow association object
workflowAssociation = GetWorkflowAssociationByName(item, associationName);                 

if (workflowAssociation == null)
  throw new Exception(string.Format  ("Workflow association '{0}' could not be found in the list '{1}'", workflowAssociationName, item.ParentList.Title)); 

//start your workflow...
item.Web.Site.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(item, workflowAssociation, workflowAssociation.AssociationData); 
   }             
   catch (SPException spEx) 
   { //log your exception } 
} 

//that kicks off a associated workflow.
StartWorkflow(anInstanceOfSPListItem, "Masood - Approval workflow")
```

Comment: Great! What if I want to write my own workflow?

Comment: You can use SharePoint designer or visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Look the [SPWorkflowManager class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowmanager_members(v=office.12).aspx). It is available  from `SPSite.WorkflowManager` property. It has `StartWorkflow`  methods to run new workflow instance.